# Как установить cookie на сайте через ajax(CORS)? На всех устройствах (desctop/mobile)

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, cors

**Как на телефоне установить куки(httpOnly) ajax (CORS) запросом?**

Мне установить cookie на десктопе при помощи `fetch(api, {creditals: 'include"})`. На сервере (nodeJS) куки отправляет такой код:

```js
res.cookie('token', '1', { maxAge: 3600000 * 24 * 7, httpOnly: true, secure: true })
res.json({
 'success': true
})
```

Вот ссылка где сайт запускает alert "All good!", если кука в первом запросе установилась и отправилась вторым на сервер. На декстопе работает отлично, **но на телефоне мой способ не работает**.

JS:

```js
fetch("https://evening-scrubland-08879.herokuapp.com" + "/getcsrftoken", {
 credentials: "include"
})
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(resData => {
  return fetch("https://evening-scrubland-08879.herokuapp.com" + "/action", {
     method: "POST",
     credentials: "include"
     }
   );
 })
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(resData => {
   alert(resData.data);
  });
```

Server NodeJS

```js
app.get("/getcsrftoken", (req, res) => {
 res.cookie("token", "1", { maxAge: 3600000 * 24 * 7, httpOnly: true, secure: true });
 res.json({
   "success": true
  })
})

app.post("/action", (req, res) => {
 let cookies = cookieExtract(req);
 let data;
 if (Number(cookies.token) === 1) {
   data = "All good!"
 } else {
   data = "No, bad..."
  }
  res.json({
    success: true,
    data
   })
 })
```

Comment: Для токенов лучше использовать `localStorage`

Comment: Плохая идея токен в localStorage  записыват